Why mysql uses index with cardinality=1?
I created table categories:
 CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `type` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `type` (`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1100001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

Then I filled table with random data:
<?php

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test_perf', 'login', 'password');

$pdo->beginTransaction();
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
    $pdo->exec("INSERT INTO categories (name, type) VALUES ('" . uniqid() . "', 1)");
}
$pdo->commit();

Statistics for table indexes:
mysql> SHOW INDEXES FROM categories;
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| categories |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |     1097250 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| categories |          1 | type     |            1 | type        | A         |           1 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
2 rows in set (0,01 sec)

It`s right, index type has only one value (1).
Then I try select by type with ignore index(type):
mysql> select MAX(name) FROM categories ignore index(type) WHERE type=1;
+---------------+
| MAX(name)     |
+---------------+
| 6769b0dfec5e7 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0,23 sec)

mysql> explain select MAX(name) FROM categories ignore index(type) WHERE type=1;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | categories | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1097250 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

And without it:
mysql> select MAX(name) FROM categories WHERE type=1;
+---------------+
| MAX(name)     |
+---------------+
| 6769b0dfec5e7 |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0,80 sec)

mysql> explain select MAX(name) FROM categories WHERE type=1;
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | categories | NULL       | ref  | type          | type | 4       | const | 548625 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

As you can see, mysql uses index type, but it only degrades performance. At the same time, the statistics are correct.
Why mysql uses index type?
Mysql version: 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.22.04.1.
I expecting mysql should not use this index.

Better question: Why does it get a different result? Did you rebuild the table between the two tests?

I think it generally assumes that searching an index is more efficient than searching the full row data. Indexes are often cached in memory.

The body of the table is (theoretically) 256 times larger than the index. ~50% of row matches the criteria, so the amount of data to be read from the disk with the index usage will be less twice then those with table scanning. The fact that the execution time with table scan is less means that the whole table is cached in memory - but the execution plan builder cannot know this and hence cannot take this into accout. Test cold execution for each query to ensure...

Then I filled table with random data All inserted rows have type=1. But only a half of rows have this value during the testing. Also - you insert 1000000 rows but the table contains 1097250  rows. How this is possible?

@Akina These are probably statistical deviations.

why not have a composite index consisting of type and name?

These are probably statistical deviations. ??? You set type to 1. If some values are not 1 then this is an error. You insert 1kk rows. If more rows is inserted then this is an error. What "statistical deviations" do you tell about?

Short answer for question Why mysql uses index type? - DBMS assume that

without index (table scan) planned to read 1097250 rows (all rows)
with index (index scan) planned read 548625 rows (half of rows)

Your explain select ... shows this.
I think for such a bad case, when there is 1 value per 1M rows, cardinality does not give a proper prediction and therefore it is simply assumed to be fifty-fifty ;)
Update2.  There is possible answer to question way index:

Each table index is queried, and the best index is used unless the optimizer believes that it is more efficient to use a table scan. At one time, a scan was used based on whether the best index spanned more than 30% of the table, but a fixed percentage no longer determines the choice between using an index or a scan.

The optimizer now is more complex and bases its estimate on additional factors such as table size, number of rows, and I/O block size.

In some cases, MySQL can read rows from the index without even consulting the data file. If all columns used from the index are numeric, only the index tree is used to resolve the query.


(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/where-optimization.html)
Third of above cases cause using index in your query.
If you change data type column type from int unsigned to varchar(5), query not use index in both cases (with ignore index and without hint).
See here example
Test model
Query model (with 100K rows) shows that it preferably performs an index scan if the cardinality of the type is >15.
Insert 100K rows.
INSERT INTO categories (name, type) VALUES (uuid() , 1);
set @@cte_max_recursion_depth=1000001;
INSERT INTO categories (name, type) 
with recursive r as(
  select 1 idx, uuid() name
    ,1 type
  union all
  select idx+1 ,uuid() name
    , 1 type                             -- model version 1
  -- , cast(rand()*15 as unsigned) type   -- version 2
  from r
  where idx<100000
)
select name,type from r;

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_stats_on_metadata';
SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata=ON;
SHOW INDEXES FROM categories;




Table
Non_unique
Key_name
Seq_in_index
Column_name
Collation
Cardinality
Sub_part
Packed
Null
Index_type
Comment
Index_comment
Visible
Expression




categories
0
PRIMARY
1
id
A
1
null
null

BTREE


YES
null


categories
1
type
1
type
A
1
null
null

BTREE


YES
null



SET profiling = 1;

Execute 2 queries
select MAX(name) FROM categories ignore index(type) WHERE type=1;




MAX(name)




37ee9640-c211-11ef-b3c7-d720191c40ee



select MAX(name) FROM categories WHERE type=1;




MAX(name)




37ee9640-c211-11ef-b3c7-d720191c40ee



SHOW PROFILES;

We can see that table scan duration is 0.04764225, index scan - 0.16639675.



Query_ID
Duration
Query




1
0.04764225
select MAX(name) FROM categories ignore index(type) WHERE type=1


2
0.16639675
select MAX(name) FROM categories WHERE type=1



explain 
select MAX(name) FROM categories ignore index(type) WHERE type=1;




id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
SIMPLE
categories
null
ALL
null
null
null
null
100001
0.00
Using where



explain 
select MAX(name) FROM categories WHERE type=1;




id
select_type
table
partitions
type
possible_keys
key
key_len
ref
rows
filtered
Extra




1
SIMPLE
categories
null
ref
type
type
4
const
50000
100.00
null



Execution statistics
explain analyze 
select MAX(name) FROM categories ignore index(type) WHERE type=1;




EXPLAIN




-> Aggregate: max(categories.`name`)  (cost=10000 rows=1) (actual time=59.1..59.1 rows=1 loops=1)    -> Filter: (categories.`type` = 1)  (cost=10000 rows=1) (actual time=0.0541..38.3 rows=100001 loops=1)        -> Table scan on categories  (cost=10000 rows=100001) (actual time=0.0524..30.8 rows=100001 loops=1)



For index scan expected rows=50K, fact rows=100K.
explain analyze 
select MAX(name) FROM categories WHERE type=1;




EXPLAIN




-> Aggregate: max(categories.`name`)  (cost=10001 rows=1) (actual time=142..142 rows=1 loops=1)    -> Index lookup on categories using type (type=1)  (cost=5001 rows=50000) (actual time=0.136..122 rows=100001 loops=1)



Exeqution time statistics



type Cardinality
without index
with index




1
0.04764225
0.16639675


5
0.03393750
0.05473025


10
0.03168700
0.04383450


15
0.03087850
0.02723575


50
0.03003600
0.00542825


500
0.03531725
0.00101600


10000
0.02948400
0.00046225



fiddle
Update1. For interest
With  create index ix_type_name on categories(type,name);
Execution time



Query_ID
Duration
Query




1
0.00073550
select MAX(name) FROM categories ignore index(type) WHERE type=1


2
0.00020950
select MAX(name) FROM categories WHERE type=1



Execution plans for both queries



EXPLAIN




-> Rows fetched before execution  (cost=0..0 rows=1) (actual time=165e-6..230e-6 rows=1 loops=1)


-> Rows fetched before execution  (cost=0..0 rows=1) (actual time=126e-6..196e-6 rows=1 loops=1)



fiddle

But mysql shouldn't use an index if it's going to need to read most of the rows anyway?

@Dmitrii, I updated answer with opinion and example. Use or not use index decision is more complex then row to read count prediction. In your case data type for column type is matter.

MySQL is using the index on the type column because it is optimized for filtering rows that match WHERE type = 1. However, in this case, the use of the index is not beneficial because the query needs to scan a large portion of rows and retrieve the MAX(name), which requires accessing the actual data rows rather than just the index.
If you want to improve performance you can try forcing a full table scan while ignoring the index like:
SELECT MAX(name) 
FROM categories 
IGNORE INDEX(type) 
WHERE type = 1;


They know how to use IGNORE INDEX, they used it in the question to make the comparison.
